# Create a task in task scheduler in VB script for windows XP

Tags: vbscript

Found a visual basic script to create a task in task scheduler. Yet it won't work even though it says it is running. I assume this is because it usses a different username. If I create a task in task scheduler manually it needs my password and uses different username. On top of this I can't seem to find a way to setup the date also instead of time only:

```
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run "AT 10:00 C:\Test.txt"
Set ObjShell = nothing
```

I would like to have the most shortest and simple code if possible. I'm not an expert in VB so bear with me please.

Comment: You need to specify a command to run, "c:\test.txt" is not a command.  Start cmd.exe and type "at /?" to get basic help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for me, none of these scripts solved my own problem as I need to install a task as the current user in Windows XP. I wrote and tested these VBScripts to try to do just that but they do add tasks and otherwise work.

This function adds a task to the task scheduler that runs under the system account. I tested this in Windows XP only but I would guess it still works in other versions of windows. You may need to tweak it a bit to get it to fit your needs. Based on [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/09/22/how-can-i-manage-scheduled-tasks-using-scripts.aspx).

```
Function ScheduleTaskWinXP(taskName)

    Dim strComputer
    strComputer = "."

    Dim objWMIService
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
        strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    ' Win32_ScheduledJob class
    ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394399(v=vs.85).aspx

    Dim objNewJob
    Set objNewJob = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ScheduledJob")

    ' Create method of the Win32_ScheduledJob class
    ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389389(v=vs.85).aspx

    Dim errJobCreated
    errJobCreated = objNewJob.Create("Notepad.exe", _
        "********123000.000000-420", True , _
        1 OR 4 OR 16, , , taskName) 

    Out errJobCreated
End Function
```

This function works in Windows 7 but does not work in Windows XP. I did not test other Windows versions. Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384054%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
Function ScheduleTaskWin7(taskName)

    ' Task Scheduler Scripting Objects
    ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383607(v=vs.85).aspx

    '------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' This sample schedules a task to start on a weekly basis.
    '------------------------------------------------------------------

    ' A constant that specifies a weekly trigger.
    const TriggerTypeWeekly = 3
    ' A constant that specifies an executable action.
    const ActionTypeExec = 0   

    '********************************************************
    ' Create the TaskService object.
    Dim service
    Set service = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
    call service.Connect()

    '********************************************************
    ' Get a folder to create a task definition in. 
    Dim rootFolder
    Set rootFolder = service.GetFolder("\")

    ' The taskDefinition variable is the TaskDefinition object.
    Dim taskDefinition
    ' The flags parameter is 0 because it is not supported.
    Set taskDefinition = service.NewTask(0) 

    '********************************************************
    ' Define information about the task.

    ' RegistrationInfo object
    ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382100(v=vs.85).aspx

    ' Set the registration info for the task by 
    ' creating the RegistrationInfo object.
    Dim regInfo
    Set regInfo = taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo
    regInfo.Description = "Start Notepad weekly."
    regInfo.Author = "Administrator"

    ' Set the task setting info for the Task Scheduler by
    ' creating a TaskSettings object.
    Dim settings
    Set settings = taskDefinition.Settings
    settings.Enabled = True
    settings.StartWhenAvailable = True
    settings.Hidden = False

    '********************************************************
    ' Create a weekly trigger. Note that the start boundary 
    ' specifies the time of day that the task starts, the 
    ' day-of-week specfies on what day of the week the task 
    ' runs, and the interval specifies what weeks the task runs.
    Dim triggers
    Set triggers = taskDefinition.Triggers

    Dim trigger
    Set trigger = triggers.Create(TriggerTypeWeekly)

    ' Trigger variables that define when the trigger is active 
    ' and the time of day that the task is run. The format of 
    ' this tims is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
    Dim startTime, endTime

    Dim time
    startTime = "2006-05-02T08:00:00"  'Task runs at 8:00 AM
    endTime = "2015-05-02T08:00:00"

    Out "startTime :" & startTime
    Out "endTime :" & endTime

    trigger.StartBoundary = startTime
    trigger.EndBoundary = endTime
    trigger.DaysOfWeek = 1
    trigger.WeeksInterval = 1    'Task runs every week.
    trigger.Id = "WeeklyTriggerId"
    trigger.Enabled = True

    '***********************************************************
    ' Create the action for the task to execute.

    ' Add an action to the task to run notepad.exe.
    Dim Action
    Set Action = taskDefinition.Actions.Create( ActionTypeExec )
    Action.Path = "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"

    Out "Task definition created. About to submit the task..."

    '***********************************************************
    ' Register (create) the task.

    call rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskName, taskDefinition, 6, , , 3)

    Out "Task submitted."

End Function
```

If you want to create a task under the current user and don't care about Windows XP, this shell command will do it:

```
schtasks /create /tn "TaskName" /tr "Executable.exe" /sc HOURLY /f
```

`/f` is invalid in Windows XP, so don't use it. Unfortunately, in Windows XP this will prompt for the current user's password.

```
schtasks /create /tn "TaskName" /tr "Executable.exe" /sc HOURLY
```

There is some documentation for this command [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and a bunch of other places.